# In yii login functionality when password is wrong

Tags: authentication, yii

In yii i am creating login functionality. When user enters correct username but wrong password i want to make serach in database for this correct username and want to put that username's id into loginattemmpt table and display wrong password message to him. So can please someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in userIdentity.php save data in table .

```
  public function authenticate() {

    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $this->username));

    if ($user === null) {
        $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    } 

    elseif($user->password !== crypt($this->password, $salt))
    {    // save $user->id in attempt table here . 
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;

    }else{
     //set id 
  }
```

and in file from where authenticate function is called setError.

```
$this->_identity = new UserIdentity($this->username, $this->password);
        if (!$this->_identity->authenticate())
            if ($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID) {
                $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect email Id');
            }elseif($this->_identity->errorCode === UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID){
                $this->addError('password', 'Incorrect Password');
            }
```

Comment: I had implemented same.i change authentic method as-if($user->password!==$user->encrypt($this->password))
{this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$command->insert('attempt', array(
  'id'=>Yii::app()->User->getId(),
)); }                                                                             but when password is wrong then "Yii::app()->User->getId()," will not contain any id. Because id field get set only when both username and password is correct.How to get that id to insert into table.How to make search using username in database

Comment: because id not set you have to fetch row match to username and save id in attemp table as.$user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $this->username)); here $user->id is userid.  save same variable to which you set in $this->_id = // id here;

Comment: thanx a lot sir...its working....                                                  Now i have to perform same login functionality. but My client side is in extjs and server side is in yii framework. Login page which will be designed in extjs will send username and password in Json format.So how to make changes to login method in order to get username and password sent by extjs in Json format.